# Time residual function in Python

Tags: python, django, time

I have 2 fields in the database: `confirmed_at` and `preparation_time`

I would like to get two simple functions that should return:

- (a) the time residual 
  and
- (b) the % of time remaining.

This is my logic which I am trying to achieve:

- when order is `confirmed_at` I update the database with `datetime.now()` and `preparation_time` is indicated in minutes and stored as `integer` (for example 5 min is stored as 5)
- `completed_time` is `confirmed_at` + `preparation_time`
- `time_remaining` is `completed_time` - `now()`
- `order status` is `completed_time` / `now()` * 100

These are my functions but I cannot make them work:

```py
def get_remaining_time(self):

    start_time = datetime(self.confirmed_at)

    end_time = (start_time + datetime.timedelta(0,self.preparation_time*60)).time() # days, seconds.

    return  end_time - datetime.now()

def get_order_status(self):
    end_time = (datetime(self.confirmed_at) + datetime.timedelta(0,self.preparation_time*60)).time()

    return end_time / datetime.now() * 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here it is the solution that I've managed to work out

```
def get_remaining_time(self):

    start_time = self.confirmed_at

    end_time = start_time + timedelta(
        0, self.preparation_time * 60
    )  # days, seconds.

    return end_time - timezone.now()

def get_time_left(self):
    left = self.get_remaining_time()

    sec = int(left.total_seconds())
    if sec > 60:
        return "{} minutes".format(int(sec / 60))
    elif sec < 60 and sec > 0:
        return "{} seconds".format(sec)
    else:
        return 0

def get_order_status(self):

    left = int(self.get_remaining_time().total_seconds())
    if left < 0:
        return 100
    else:
        return round((1 - left / (self.preparation_time * 60)) * 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of type returned from functions? If it's timedelta - just turn it into date.